# Sugarcrm CE 6.5 : Как заменить html subpanel-и на свой?

Tags: php, crm

Я создал модуль и в виде субпанели отображаю в аккаунтах.
И хочу конкретно для этого модуля изменить html код на свой.

Как можно заменить ту часть html на свой там, где отображаются субпанели ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а не проще на спец. форуме задать вопрос?

Comment: @n.osennij Конечно проще, а смысл .... Два вопроса до сих пор торчат

Answer (score 2):

Для ответа требуется более подробная информация связанная с кодом,однако общий алгоритм можно дать. Вы должны подключиться к вашей CRM через IDE или скачать его. 
После чего вы должны нажать F12 и квадратик с мышкой в левом углу. Навести на элемент и скинуть его код для менее расплывчатого ответа сюда. Хотя я уверен что у элемента есть ID. Ну а дальше, когда вы получите ID вы можете управлять выводом на уровне PHP и да заменить вообще весь Div javascript, что не очень сложная задача. Так что полагаю, что для более точного ответа, вам нужно найти функцию в вашей папке и выложить кусок кода блока, так как экспертов в PHP много, но не у всех есть глубокие знания в CRM.
Если же ваш модуль не имеет id, пожалуйста сделайте его для вашей задачи, ну или докопайтесь до элемента и скиньте gist.

Comment: Тут скорей нужны специфичные знания.Если вы не знакомы с этой системой то бесполезно пытаться отвечать.